# What does [vmuser@localhost ~]$ mean?

Tags: shell, prompt

What does the `vmuser`, `localhost`, `~`, and `$` mean in:

```
[vmuser@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 5):

`vmuser` is the username of currently logged on user.

`localhost` is the name of the computer on which current shell session is running.

`~` means current directory is set to logged on user's home directory.

`$` is an arbitrary marker delimiting information to the left and command field to the right of it. As to why it's `$` by default, refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/57575/493903) on SuperUser.

What you refer to is called a shell prompt and can be customized to suit individual user's needs. Here is a sample guide for [customization in Bash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization).